# Invalid cursor when fetch

Tags: oracle, plsql

I can't execute this anonymous procedure, when I fetch the cursor `c_ev` I get an *invalid cursor* error.

The source code of the anonymous procedure and the stored code are here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
  PROCEDURE jorge_ResulPartidosPorJornada (p_cod_jor integer,C_partidos OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, C_EV OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  BEGIN

  OPEN C_EV FOR
    SELECT P.RESULTADOEV, E.NOMBRE
    FROM PARTIDOS P, EQUIPOS E
    WHERE P.JORNADA_COD=P_COD_JOR
    AND P.CODEQUIPO_VISITANTE=E.COD;      
   CLOSE C_EV;   

  END;
```

```
declare 
    C_PARTIDOS SYS_REFCURSOR;
    C_EL SYS_REFCURSOR;

    R_EV PARTIDOS.RESULTADOEV%TYPE;
    N_EV EQUIPOS.NOMBRE%TYPE;
    jornada integer;

begin

    jornada:= 1;
    jorge_ResulPartidosPorJornada(jornada, C_PARTIDOS,C_EV);

    FETCH C_EV INTO R_EV,N_EV;
    WHILE C_EV%FOUND LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(R_EV);
        FETCH C_EV INTO R_EV,N_EV;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: your procedure `jorge_ResulPartidosPorJornada` takes three parameters but you are attempting to call it with four, and you also don't declare the variable `C_EV` in your PL/SQL block.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes, because the original has 4, but here I only show what gives me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake you made was when you **closed** the cursor in `jorge_`something procedure.

If you don't (I used Scott's sample tables as I don't have yours), it works:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure jorge
  2    (p_cod_jor  in  integer,
  3     c_partidos out sys_refcursor,
  4     c_ev       out sys_refcursor
  5    )
  6  as
  7  begin
  8    open c_ev for                                       --> don't close it!
  9      select empno, ename from emp where deptno = 10;   
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2      c_partidos sys_refcursor;
  3      c_el       sys_refcursor;
  4      r_ev       emp.empno%type;
  5      n_ev       emp.ename%type;
  6      jornada    integer;
  7  begin
  8      jornada := 1;
  9      jorge (jornada, c_partidos, c_el);
 10
 11      loop
 12        fetch c_el into r_ev,n_ev;
 13        exit when c_el%notfound;
 14        dbms_output.put_line(r_ev ||' '|| n_ev);
 15      end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
7782 CLARK
7839 KING
7934 MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you do close it, it won't work:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure jorge
  2    (p_cod_jor  in  integer,
  3     c_partidos out sys_refcursor,
  4     c_ev       out sys_refcursor
  5    )
  6  as
  7  begin
  8    open c_ev for
  9      select empno, ename from emp where deptno = 10;
 10    close c_ev;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2      c_partidos sys_refcursor;
  3      c_el       sys_refcursor;
  4      r_ev       emp.empno%type;
  5      n_ev       emp.ename%type;
  6      jornada    integer;
  7  begin
  8      jornada := 1;
  9      jorge (jornada, c_partidos, c_el);
 10
 11      loop
 12        fetch c_el into r_ev,n_ev;
 13        exit when c_el%notfound;
 14        dbms_output.put_line(r_ev ||' '|| n_ev);
 15      end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at line 12


SQL>
```

---

By the way, your code won't work anyway. You declared `C_EL` and used `C_EV`

```
C_EL SYS_REFCURSOR;

jorge_ResulPartidosPorJornada(jornada, C_PARTIDOS, C_EV);
                                                   ^^^^
                                               should be C_EL
```

but that's probably just a typo.